# Duvida como montar socket em jogo da velha em Python

Tags: python, socket

Tenho um trabalho no curso de programação em redes e nos foi solicitado utilizar um código de jogo e fazer um cliente e servidor utilizando `sockets`, porém a explicação de meu professor foi muito vaga e ele não da suporte algum aos alunos.

Já montei de tudo quanto e jeito e nunca da certo a conexão entre cliente e servidor, não sei exatamente como deveria montar cliente e servidor.
poderiam me dar uma mão? já catei em tudo que é lugar e nada tem uma explicação de como dividir um código entre cliente e servidor e usar o `socket` junto.

```
#
# Jogo da Velha
#

# O tabuleiro
velha="""  Jogadas      Posições jogáveis
   |   |           7 | 8 | 9
---+---+---       ---+---+---
   |   |           4 | 5 | 6
---+---+---       ---+---+---
   |   |           1 | 2 | 3
"""
# Listagem de posicoes (horizontal e vertical) para as posicoes do jogo.
# Numeração das posicoes ira facilitar o entendimento para jogabilidade.


posicoes = [
  None,  # Indice
  (5, 1), # 1
  (5, 5), # 2
  (5, 9), # 3
  (3, 1), # 4
  (3, 5), # 5
  (3, 9), # 6
  (1, 1), # 7
  (1, 5), # 8
  (1, 9), # 9
]

# Descrição das posicoes que ganham o jogo fazendo uma linha, um coluna, linha ou diagonal == win
# Os números representam as posicoes ganhadoras
win = [
      [ 1, 2, 3], #linha
      [ 4, 5, 6],
      [ 7, 8, 9],
      [ 7, 4, 1], #coluna
      [ 8, 5, 2],
      [ 9, 6, 3],
      [ 7, 5, 3], #diag
      [ 1, 5, 9]
    ]

# Tabuleiro é construido usndo string e gera lista

tabuleiro = []
for linha in velha.splitlines():
tabuleiro.append(list(linha))

jogador = "X" # Começa jogando com X
jogando = True
jogada = 0 # Contador de jogadas
while True:
for t in tabuleiro:  # Mostra o tabuleiro
    print("".join(t))
if not jogando: # Termina após mostrar o último tabuleiro
    break
if jogada == 9: # Se 9 jogadas, todas as posicoes já foram preenchidas
    print("Deu velha! Ninguém ganhou.")
    break
jogada = int(input("Digite a posição a jogar 1-9 (jogador %s):" % jogador))
if jogada<1 or jogada>9:
    print("Posição inválida")
    continue
# Verifica posição livre
if tabuleiro[posicoes[jogada][0]][posicoes[jogada][1]] != " ":
    print("Posição ja utilizada ocupada.");
    continue
# Marca a jogada p/ o jogador
tabuleiro[posicoes[jogada][0]][posicoes[jogada][1]] = jogador
# Verfica se ganhou
for p in win:
    for x in p:
        if tabuleiro[posicoes[x][0]][posicoes[x][1]] != jogador:
            break
    else: # Se o for terminar sem break, todas as posicoes de p pertencem ao mesmo jogador
        print("O jogador %s ganhou (%s): "%(jogador, p))
        jogando = False
        break
jogador = "X" if jogador == "O" else "O" # Alterna os jogador
jogada +=1 # Contador de jogadas
```

Comment: Você tem que fazer o cliente e o servidor? ou só o cliente?

Comment: tipo a ideia é fazer os dois cliente e servidor, só não tenho ideia de como dividir esse codigo e aonde encaixar o socket.

Comment: Da forma que está sua pergunta está muito ampla. Acredito que você possa dividir seu problema em várias partes e, se necessário, fazer uma pergunta relativa a cada parte. Comece estudando o pacote `socket` do Python e tente criar uma comunicação entre dois computadores. Se tiver dificuldade nisso, faça a pergunta somente deste assunto.

Comment: Vc já leu a documentação do Python --> 1) https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html
2) https://pymotw.com/2/socket/tcp.html

Comment: Ja li.. entendi como o socket funciona, só não consegui entender como eu faria a montagem cliente e servidor a distribuição do código entre os dois unindo o socket.( minha lógica é bem fraca tenho uma dificuldade bem séria pra entender)

Comment: dica: leia primeiro sobre funções, e reformule o seu protótio suando funções.  nao vai ser impossível até começar.